# Not rebooting to the lastest kernel after update to grub 2

Tags: apt, grub2, kernel, reboot

I'm used to installing ubuntu core updates from apt, and then rebooting to get to the latest kernel.    However, this process doesn't seem to be working right on one of my servers.   Kernel 4.10.0-21 is installed but the machine only seems to use 4.10.0-20 when it reboots.

During the [apt update process to grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading), a dialog asked me if I want to chain my legacy grub configuration.   I chose "no".   I think that may be part of the problem.

[image]

Updating grub seems to do the right thing, it puts the newest kernel first:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-20-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

My `/etc/grub/default` file says that kernel 0 should be the default:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I can verify that `grub.cfg` gets the kernels added:

```
$ grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
...
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-21-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-21-generic-advanced-6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-21-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-21-generic-recovery-6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-20-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-20-generic-advanced-6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-20-generic-recovery-6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97' {
...

$ grep -Poz "menuentry 'Ubuntu' (.|\n)*?\}" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic root=UUID=6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-21-generic
}
```

The kernel file actually exists on disk:

```
$ ls -l /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7575312 Apr 28 06:41 /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic
```

On the chance that it was corrupted somehow, I tried re-installing it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.10.0-21-generic
```

dpkg shows that both kernels are installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ii | grep linux-image-[0-9].*-generic
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-20-generic               4.10.0-20.22                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-21-generic               4.10.0-21.23                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

However after rebooting:

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-20-generic

$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 4.10.0-20-generic (buildd@lcy01-05) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170406 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) ) #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:42 UTC 2017

$ cat /proc/cmdline
root=UUID=6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97 ro quiet splash
```

I really think that grub legacy is somehow still being used on this machine.   /boot/grub/menu.1st has references to 20 but not to 21:

```
title           Ubuntu 17.04, kernel 4.10.0-20-generic
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic root=UUID=6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97 ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-20-generic
quiet

title           Ubuntu 17.04, kernel 4.10.0-20-generic (recovery mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic root=UUID=6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97 ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-20-generic

title           Ubuntu 17.04, kernel 4.8.0-49-generic
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-49-generic root=UUID=6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97 ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-49-generic
quiet

title           Ubuntu 17.04, kernel 4.8.0-49-generic (recovery mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-49-generic root=UUID=6af3f559-58c5-4c56-b1c8-ffe02c700c97 ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-49-generic

title           Ubuntu 17.04, memtest86+
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/memtest86+.bin
quiet
```

This machine is in a data center, and I don't have console access during the reboot process.   I'm unable to see what grub says during the reboot, I can only ssh in after it is up and running.

What could be causing the newest kernel not to be used and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check in grub.conf which kernel is defined as default

Comment: What is the output of: `grep 'menuentry ' /boot/grub/grub.cfg  | grep -Po "Linux.*?generic"`

Comment: `grep -Poz "menuentry 'Ubuntu' (.|\n)*?\}" /boot/grub/grub.cfg` Add the output to see what is going on on first menu entry.

Comment: everything seems fine, what about `ls -l /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58835/discussion-between-ravexina-and-stephen-ostermiller).

Comment: It would  be good to know the output of `dpkg -l | grep ii | grep linux-image-[0-9].*-generic` too.

Comment: What about: `cat /proc/version` and `cat /proc/cmdline`?

Comment: Sure, I put those in too.

Comment: I also added the contents of menu.1st which has references to 4.10.0-20 but not to 4.10.0-21

Comment: Saw it, you can add a new menu in `menu.lst` manually for new Kernel, you can also run remove grub legacy and reinstall grub2, then: `grub-install /dev/sda` and `update-grub` should do the job.

Comment: That was it @Ravexina, grub2 was not installed into the boot sector.   After running `grub-install /dev/sda` it reboots to the newest kernel.   I found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading has all the screenshots I saw during the apt-update this morning.   I'm not sure why apt chose today to install grub2 on this machine.   When I chose not to chain them, I assumed that grub2 would replace grub-legacy, but that appears not to be the case without some intervention.  Thank you for all your help!   Please submit an answer, and I will accept.

Comment: You're welcome ;) Glad that problem solved ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first look, everything seems fine, your `grub.cfg`, `/etc/default/grub`, Kernel installation status, everything is as it should be.

However if we check `cat /proc/version` as your output says grub is loading a wrong Kernel:

```
Linux version 4.10.0-20-generic ...
```

And as you mentioned you've got GRUB Legacy on your system, so I guess GRUB 2 is not installed on your boot sector in general.

so run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

to install the `grub2` on boot sector.

Then to make sure everything is correct run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to regenerate the `grub.cfg`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not running server, but desktop.  I did notice something strange during my updating to 4.10.0-21.23...

At the end of the update process there was output in the terminal that said:

```
The link /vmlinuz.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link vmlinuz.old 
you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
```

I re-ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Just to be safe before rebooting.